# SNMP Builder zabbix 2.2.1

Tags: snmp, zabbix

Hello I try implement snmpbuilder for my zabbix for this repo https://github.com/atimonin/snmpbuilder , but when I try open zabbix ( Configuration -> SNMP Builder) , I see this error:

Screen:

[image]

```
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
Undefined index: hostid [snmp_builder.php:464 → get_templates() in /usr/share/zabbix/snmp_builder.php:961]
```

Anybody have some idea what's wrong ?

Regards 
Mick

Answer (score 0):

According to the repository history, the patch seems to be provided for Zabbix 2.0.5 the latest, whereas you are trying to use the patch on Zabbix 2.2.3.

Comment: Solution for this issue. There is tested on zabbix version 2.2.1, 2.2.4 and 2.2.6. Below I share link: http://wikibaseofknowledge.blogspot.com/2014/10/zabbix-snmp-builder.html